# Apply CSS theme based on react state

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a REACT application (bootstrapped with `create react app` and `react-bootstrap`) for which I am trying to add option to switch to DARK theme if user enabled this in his settings. I am storing the settings on server and fetching them into properties.

I have a separate stylesheet called `dark.css` where all my component styles are overriden.

dark.css (example):

```
#root {
  background-color: var(--dark);
  color: var(--light)
}

.card {
   background-color: var(--dark); // overriding bootstrap styles here 
}
```

I am trying to apply it at the root of my application like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
        if (this.props.profile && this.props.profile.theme === 'dark') {
            require('./styles/dark.css');
        }
    }
```

It works great when running the application locally with `yarn start`. But when I actually build the app using webpack, it works really strange. Part of the new styles are applied and part on, regardless of which theme is selected. For example background is applied from the main theme and ignored in the dark theme but text color is the opposite.

Why is this happening?

It seems that the dark stylesheet is not being applied at all when building the app with webpack, although everything looks correctly when running it with `yarn start`.

Comment: Please share your webpack.config

Comment: I am using react scripts for everything. I have not touched the webpack config. It is abstracted from me.

Comment: When you activate dark mode, then refresh, does everything correct itself?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I solved my issue by wrapping my app into dynamic class and loading all css files regardless of the selected theme (see answer). This seems to work great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issues simply by importing all styled css sheets and then prefixing them like this:

```
.dark .card {
   color: black;
}

.light .card {
   color: white;
}
```

I assign class to the wrapper based on my props:

```
<div id="root" className={theme}>
   // content
</div>
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have a naming clashes, which overrides your css.

React supports [CSS Modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) alongside regular stylesheets using the `[name].module.css` file naming convention.

CSS Modules let you use the same CSS class name in different files without **worrying about naming clashes**

Comment: But this would mean that I have to reference the style in every component. I would like to override bootstrap styles globaly by loading the css.

Comment: @Smajl Can you please check in dev-tools if your css is being override by bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, they are overriden. I don;t understand why because it seems that it uses part of those styles even when they are not imported...

Comment: Not sure that I understand your last comment, can you please provide an example?